# C# Automapper, Two into One Based on ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, automapper

I recently started to use automapper, I got through the documentation but couldn't find or simply misunderstood some concepts. Well, my question is: Is there a way to merge two collections into one where source collections A and B have the same ID. Currently, I am mapping only from collection A, leaving some properties unassigned. I want to assign those properties from collection B. Summarizing, I'd like to get a collection C populated with objects containing AB based on one ID.

This is my code at the moment:

```
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => {
                c.AllowNullCollections = true;
                c.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
                c.CreateMap<PaymentsReport, TaxCalculationData>();
            });
            var mapper = new Mapper(config);
            
            IEnumerable<TaxCalculationData> taxCalculationsX = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TaxCalculationData>>(PaymentsReport).ToList();
```

Hopefully, my explanation is understandable, all suggestions will be very appreciated. Meantime I keep googling.

Comment: Automapper doesn't understand keys/joins like this. You need to merge the two collections into one using something like linq's `Zip` or `Join` method, making a collection of objects which contain both A and B. Then Automapper can map the tuple to your expected type, taking properties from A or B according to your mapping profile

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot ! I will try to do it this way then.

Comment: `AutoMapper.Collection` does that.

Comment: Cold You explain something more, please?